# Legend composition for bar and line plots

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I have some meteorological data which I'm plotting as a time series showing monthly averages. I have rainfall as a barplot and temperature as a line plot on the same plot canvas. I need to generate a legend with different symbols in, i.e. a coloured box for the rainfall, and two coloured lines for the temperature.

Here's the data

```
   >  month    max_temp    min_temp     rain        humid
    >     Jan   24.65032258 12.54193548 1.425806452 75.44064516
    >     Feb   25.65248227 13.39219858 1.876595745 79.06666667
    >     Mar   24.26129032 12.41354839 2.318709677 83.55806452
    >     Apr   21.038      10.62933333 5.013333333 90.026
    >     May   17.29548387 7.16516129  4.080645161 91.83225806
    >     Jun   14.98733333 5.529333333 4.4         91.2
    >     Jul   13.98516129 4.06516129  3.987096774 90.60322581
    >     Aug   15.18258065 5.316129032 3.350322581 89.26129032
    >     Sep   16.434      7.668       4.229333333 84.03666667
    >     Oct   18.13225806 8.481290323 2.277419355 81.26129032
    >     Nov   20.07666667 9.558666667 2.562       75.99266667
    >     Dec   22.51032258 12.13225806 2.296774194 76.28193548
```

And here's my code to generate the plot

```
weather<-weather
month_number<-seq(1,12,1)
months<-months[1:12]
new<-data.frame(rain=c(weather$rain),order=c(months))
graph<-barplot(height=new$rain, names.arg=new$order,col="light blue",
  cex.axis=0.2,border=NA,xaxt='n',yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",ylim=c(0,10))
axis(side=1, pos=0,tck=-0.05,at=graph, labels=months[1:12],cex.axis=0.7,las=2,font.axis=2)
axis(4,las="1",cex.axis=0.7,font.axis=2)
mtext("Accumulated rainfall (mm)",side=4,line=2,cex=0.7)
par(new=TRUE)
weather$x<-month_number
plot(weather$x,weather$max_temp,type="l",las=1,col="red",lwd=1.5,xaxt="n",
     ylim=c(0,30),xlab=NA,ylab = expression(paste("Temperature ",degree,"C")),
     ,cex.lab=0.8,cex.axis=0.7,font.axis=2)
lines(weather$x,weather$min_temp,col="blue",lwd=1.5)
legend("bottom",inset=c(0,1.05),legend=c("Rainfall", "Max temp", "Min temp"),xpd=TRUE,
       ,horiz=TRUE,pch=c(15),col=c("light blue","red","blue"),
       lty=c(0,1,1),lwd=2,title=NA,cex=0.6,bty='n')
```

And the plot itself. In the legend, I'd like to increase the size of the rainfall plot character and omit altogether the plot characters shown in the lines for both temperatures. The font size needs to remain the same. I've tried `pch=26` which I've [seen plots a null character](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-May/033309.html) but I get an error message. Also [looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597262/combining-line-and-barplot-legend-in-r) but it didn't solve my problem.

[image: Weather data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would omit the plot characters in the lines (e.g. use `pch=c(19,NA,NA)`):

```
legend("bottom",inset=c(0,1.05),legend=c("Rainfall", "Max temp", "Min temp"),xpd=TRUE,
       ,horiz=TRUE,pch=c(19,NA,NA),col=c("light blue","red","blue"), 
       lty=c(0,1,1),lwd=2,title=NA,cex=0.6,bty='n')
```

To get the plot characters not in the lines and to make the rainfall plot character bigger, I would actually use `fill`:

```
legend("bottom",inset=c(0,1.05),legend=c("Rainfall", "Max temp", "Min temp"),xpd=TRUE,
       ,horiz=TRUE,col=c("light blue","red","blue"), fill=c("light blue", NA,NA), border = c("light blue", NA,NA),
       lty=c(0,1,1),lwd=2,title=NA,cex=0.6,bty='n')
```